# Rails newbie - am I missing something really obvious?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Quite experienced but self taught with PHP/MySQL and playing about with Rails. Really love what i've done with it do so far but am seriously struggling with what in my mind should be really simple; joining data from various tables together and then displaying it in various views. I think I get the concept of Active Record, I just can't seem to get it to work they way I want.

I'm working on building a fairly involved music cataloging system ala Discogs, with artist, release, product, track and label levels and have the following models:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :releases
end

class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :release
has_many :tracks
end

class Tracks < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

Eventually, I want to introduce territories, sales and other data but until I nail the basics above I can't move fwd.

In my products controller I have:

```
@product = Product.find(:all, :include => :release)
```

Which produces:

```
Processing by ProductsController#index as HTML
Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" 
Release Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "releases".* FROM "releases" WHERE "releases"."id" IN (1, 2, 3, 10, 4)
```

But I am thinking this might be unnecessary if my associations are correct?

In my products view for example I want to list products with the title pulled in from the releases table. I've tried the following but get a 'NoMethodError' on title:

```
<% @product.each do |product| %>

<tr>    
<td><%= product.title %></td>
<td><%= product.cat_no %></td>
<td><%= product.barcode %></td>
<td></td>

</tr>
<% end %>
```

Help!!

Massive thanks in advance.

Ryan

Comment: I can see you are rather confused by this. I think you are missing a lot of things here (for example, you should have a `has_and_belongs_to_many :artists` in your Release model) so instead of correcting you, I advise you to check out http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/4/20/many-to-many-dance-off. It has everything you need to move forward with this

Comment: Haha, i'd say frustrated! It should be simple right? I guess I am trying to run before I can walk.

Thanks for the comment, i'll check out your blog now.

Comment: Oh, the blog isn't mine. I happened to discover it while learning about rails and researching on how to implement joins models and tables and that site has been invaluable to me ever since. It's really good and it explains the main differences between using `HABTM` relationships and `has_many :through` relationships (which I think is what you want!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Release Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "releases".* FROM "releases" WHERE "releases"."id" IN (1, 2, 3, 10, 4)
```

The above query is generated because you have used :include=>:association(:release in your case) in find method.This the property of Rails is called as eager loading widely used for performance optimization.There is no problem in your association I think.

If you have used

@products = Product.all

And in your view page

```
<% @product.each do |product| %>
 <tr>    
  <td><%= product.title %></td>
  <td><%= product.cat_no %></td>
  <td><%= product.barcode %></td>
  <td><%= product.release.name %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

The method call product.release will create the above query for the 'n' number of times the loop executed.(n database hits)

If you use :include option this can be avoided.Rails preloads the related association(:release).(only 1 databse hit)

For more details visit

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thanks. I've changed my controller to use 

@products = Product(:all) 

But I now get undefined method `Product' for my product controller :(

Comment: Changed to @products = Product.all and cleared that error :-)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is :

> I've tried the following but get a 'NoMethodError' on title:

according to his code:

```
<td><%= product.title %></td>
```

I am wondering if you missed the "title" column in your "product" table, and I suggest that you should check your table's structure to make sure this column exists.

Comment: The title column is in the releases table......I basically want to set up a master 'Release' and then each product is a variant of the release......so the master release would be 'Dark Side Of The Moon' for example and I then would add the variants or products each identified by format/catalogue number/release date etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `"rake db:migrate"` in your console to update your database. If you have generated the product model, but not remembered to migrate the db, the table wont be in the database. You might also have forgotten to add the product.title in as a migration/part of your database.